# Prove that null$T_1\subset$ null$T_2$ if and only if there exists $S\in\mathcal L(W,W)$ such that $T_2=ST_1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

While reading this solution, it occurred to me that $V$ is not necessarily a direct sum of $K$ and $\operatorname{null}(T_1)$. If we extend $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ to a basis $\{v_1, v2, \ldots, v_n, u_1, \ldots, u_m\}$ of $V$, will such an $S$ still exist for the rest of the proof when $Tv_1, Tv_2, \ldots, Tv_n, Tu_1, \ldots, Tu_m$ may no longer be linearly independent?

[image]

Comment: See [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: You don't extend $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ to a full basis casually. Instead, by rank-nullity theorem, the dimension of $\dim K+\dim\operatorname{null}(T_1)=\dim V$. Therefore, if you can show that $K\cap\operatorname{null}(T_1)=0$, then $K\oplus\operatorname{null}(T_1)$ is a direct sum of dimension $\dim V$ and hence it must be equal to $V$.